# Add fields from array of JSON objects based on specific field

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of objects ...

```
[  
   {  
      "matchID":"-LP0LKl_nR4VQf6Gxwz8",
      "playerId":"YvtwVY1gsZSzI7ZQzyDTZbSwdLF3",
      "points":"11",
      "id":"-LP1WvT4eN1L7BLbyhJt"
   },
   {  
      "matchID":"-LP0LKl_nR4VQf6Gxwz8",
      "playerId":"YabcVY1gsZSzI7ZQzyDTZbSwdLF6",
      "points":"23",
      "id":"-TP1WvT4eN1L7GeYyhJt"
   },
   {  
      "matchID":"-DF0LKl_nR4VQf6Gxwz7",
      "playerId":"YabcVY1gsZSzI7ZQzyDTZbSwdLF6",
      "points":"12",
      "id":"-GH1WvT4eN1L7GeYyhJt"
   },
   {  
      "matchID":"-DF0LKl_nR4VQf6Gxwz7",
      "playerId":"YvtwVY1gsZSzI7ZQzyDTZbSwdLF3",
      "points":"6",
      "id":"-XZ1WvR2eN1L7GeYyhJt"
   }
]
```

I want to loop through this array and create a new array that is a basically just each playerId and their total points for all matches.

So after cycling through the above, the array would look like ..

```
 [{"palyerId": "YabcVY1gsZSzI7ZQzyDTZbSwdLF6", "points": "35"},{"palyerId": "YvtwVY1gsZSzI7ZQzyDTZbSwdLF3", "points": "17"}]
```

Comment: When you clicked to create this post the button said "Ask Question". But "I want" or "I need" is not a question. We will help you fix bugs, not just do your work for you completely. What research have you done? What code have you tried? What problem are you facing? Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for further guidance on how to ask a useful question.

Answer (score 2):

A non reduce version with a for loop looks like the following (again, the central idea is to group by `playerId`):

```js
let data = [{
    "matchID": "-LP0LKl_nR4VQf6Gxwz8",
    "playerId": "YvtwVY1gsZSzI7ZQzyDTZbSwdLF3",
    "points": "11",
    "id": "-LP1WvT4eN1L7BLbyhJt"
  },
  {
    "matchID": "-LP0LKl_nR4VQf6Gxwz8",
    "playerId": "YabcVY1gsZSzI7ZQzyDTZbSwdLF6",
    "points": "23",
    "id": "-TP1WvT4eN1L7GeYyhJt"
  },
  {
    "matchID": "-DF0LKl_nR4VQf6Gxwz7",
    "playerId": "YabcVY1gsZSzI7ZQzyDTZbSwdLF6",
    "points": "12",
    "id": "-GH1WvT4eN1L7GeYyhJt"
  },
  {
    "matchID": "-DF0LKl_nR4VQf6Gxwz7",
    "playerId": "YvtwVY1gsZSzI7ZQzyDTZbSwdLF3",
    "points": "6",
    "id": "-XZ1WvR2eN1L7GeYyhJt"
  }
];

var res = {};
for (let d of data) {
  if (d.playerId in res) res[d.playerId].points += parseInt(d.points);
  else res[d.playerId] = {playerId: d.playerId, points: parseInt(d.points)};
}

console.log(Object.values(res));
```

Comment: Hi Slider, I might have done something wrong but when I try to implement this solution in Chrome browser dev tools. It seems to tally all the scores with playerId undefined. So I get ...playerId: undefined, points: 52.

Comment: @chucknor you have a typo in your keys (`palyerId` vs `playerId`).

Comment: Yes, you're right. Your code works. Thanks. I fixed that in above data.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `reduce()` to loop thru the array. Use `new Map()` to group the array. And use spread operator to convert the map object into an array.

```js
var arr = [{"matchID":"-LP0LKl_nR4VQf6Gxwz8","palyerId":"YvtwVY1gsZSzI7ZQzyDTZbSwdLF3","points":"11","id":"-LP1WvT4eN1L7BLbyhJt"},{"matchID":"-LP0LKl_nR4VQf6Gxwz8","palyerId":"YabcVY1gsZSzI7ZQzyDTZbSwdLF6","points":"23","id":"-TP1WvT4eN1L7GeYyhJt"},{"matchID":"-DF0LKl_nR4VQf6Gxwz7","palyerId":"YabcVY1gsZSzI7ZQzyDTZbSwdLF6","points":"12","id":"-GH1WvT4eN1L7GeYyhJt"},{"matchID":"-DF0LKl_nR4VQf6Gxwz7","palyerId":"YvtwVY1gsZSzI7ZQzyDTZbSwdLF3","points":"6","id":"-XZ1WvR2eN1L7GeYyhJt"}]

var result = [...arr.reduce((c, v) => {
  if (!c.has(v.palyerId)) c.set(v.palyerId, {"palyerId": v.palyerId,"points": 0});
  c.get(v.palyerId).points += +v.points;
  return c;
}, new Map()).values()];

console.log(result);
```

---

Or you can `reduce()` the array into an object using the  `palyerId` as the key. Use `Object.values()` to convert the object into an array.

```js
var arr = [{"matchID":"-LP0LKl_nR4VQf6Gxwz8","palyerId":"YvtwVY1gsZSzI7ZQzyDTZbSwdLF3","points":"11","id":"-LP1WvT4eN1L7BLbyhJt"},{"matchID":"-LP0LKl_nR4VQf6Gxwz8","palyerId":"YabcVY1gsZSzI7ZQzyDTZbSwdLF6","points":"23","id":"-TP1WvT4eN1L7GeYyhJt"},{"matchID":"-DF0LKl_nR4VQf6Gxwz7","palyerId":"YabcVY1gsZSzI7ZQzyDTZbSwdLF6","points":"12","id":"-GH1WvT4eN1L7GeYyhJt"},{"matchID":"-DF0LKl_nR4VQf6Gxwz7","palyerId":"YvtwVY1gsZSzI7ZQzyDTZbSwdLF3","points":"6","id":"-XZ1WvR2eN1L7GeYyhJt"}]

var result = Object.values(arr.reduce((c, {palyerId,points}) => {
  c[palyerId] = c[palyerId] || {palyerId,points: 0};
  c[palyerId].points += +points;
  return c;
}, {}));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Happy to help :)